# How to get a user by email in JIRA Script Runner

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

When writing a Groovy script for [JIRA Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview), how do you get a user, or just their username, given their email address?

It seems that you're supposed to use the `findUsersByEmail` method in the `UserSearchService` interface.

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.0.2/com/atlassian/jira/bc/user/search/UserSearchService.html

But how do you get an instance of this class?

Related question: [How to get a user by email in a JIRA plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853662/how-to-get-a-user-by-email-in-a-jira-plugin).
The difference is that question is about a plugin, and my question is about JIRA Script Runner.

This code does not work:

```
setUserProperties(httpMethod: "POST", groups: ["jira-administrators"])
{ MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body, HttpServletRequest request ->

    def userPropertyManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserPropertyManager()
    def userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager()
    def userSearchService = DefaultUserPickerSearchService;
    def users = userSearchService.findUsersByEmail("felicity.smoak@queenconsolidated.com")

    users.each {
        aUser ->
            userPropertyManager.getPropertySet(aUser).setString("jira.meta.Company", "Smoak Technologies")
    }

    return Response.ok(users).build();
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
2016-04-18 15:23:06,168 ERROR [common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint]: *************************************************************************************
2016-04-18 15:23:06,168 ERROR [common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint]: Script endpoint failed on method: POST setUserProperties
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.search.DefaultUserPickerSearchService.findUsersByEmail() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [felicity.smoak@queenconsolidated.com]
Possible solutions: findUsersByEmail(java.lang.String), findUserKeysByEmail(java.lang.String)
    at Script462$_run_closure3.doCall(Script462.groovy:40)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint.doEndpoint(UserCustomScriptEndpoint.groovy:308)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint.postUserEndpoint(UserCustomScriptEndpoint.groovy:208)
```

**EDIT**

Based on @Oldskultxo's and @BjörnKautler suggestions, this is now my working code:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.user.*
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.search.UserSearchService
import com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserManager
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import groovy.json.*
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

setUserProperties(httpMethod: "POST", groups: ["jira-administrators"])
{ MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body, HttpServletRequest request ->

    def userPropertyManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserPropertyManager()
    def userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager()
    def userSearchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(UserSearchService.class)
    def users = userSearchService.findUsersByEmail("felicity.smoak@queenconsolidated.com")

    users.each {
        aUser ->
            userPropertyManager.getPropertySet(aUser).setString("jira.meta.Company", "Smoak Technologies")
    }

    return Response.ok("200").build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ComponentAccessor.getComponent(UserSearchService)` to get the right service if there is no concrete `getUserSearchService()` method.

Comment: The variable `UserSearchService` is undeclared, and cannot find the matching method `com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor#getComponent(java.lang.Object)`

Comment: Of course you either have to import the `UserSearchService` class or use FQCN like `com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor.getComponent(com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.search.UserSearchService)`

Comment: Also upvoting this answer because `def userSearchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(UserSearchService.class)` also compiles and gives me the result I want.

Comment: As long as you use this in Groovy, you don't need the `.class`. The `.class` is only necessary if you use this in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get components this way:

```
ComponentManager.getComponentInstanceOfType(UserSearchService.class);
```

And then just look for its methods.

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand _And then just look for its methods._ - are you maybe working in an IDE with auto completion?

Comment: nop. I mean then you can look for methods in the api. and use them at it is shown.  https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/user/search/UserSearchService.html   aAnd here look for the method:  findUsersByEmail(String email). Excuse me for the confusion. :)

Comment: Okay. I know about that website, that's where I got `findUsersByEmail` in the first place - as you can see in the link of line 3 of my question. Only difference is, I am looking at `7.0.2` and you are looking at `latest`. But `ComponentManager` and `UserSearchService` are undeclared.

Comment: Have your tried with that line?? it works since Jira's older versions than 7.0.2     https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.0.2/com/atlassian/jira/bc/user/search/UserSearchService.html    And the definition of component manager for that jira version:  https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.0.2/com/atlassian/jira/ComponentManager.html

Comment: I tried with exactly that line as it is in your answer, without the semicolon because that's not needed in Groovy, and Script Runner gives static type errors.

Comment: `[Static type checking] - The variable [ComponentManager] is undeclared. @ line 40, column 5.` and `[Static type checking] - The variable [UserSearchService] is undeclared. @ line 40, column 5.`

Comment: `{"message":"No such property: ComponentManager for class: Script514","stack-trace":"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ComponentManager for class: Script514\n\tat Script514$_run_closure3.doCall(Script514.groovy:40)\n\tat com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint.doEndpoint(UserCustomScriptEndpoint.groovy:308)\n\tat com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint.postUserEndpoint(UserCustomScriptEndpoint.groovy:208)\n","status-code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}%`

Comment: Have you add the import like this? import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager

Comment: No I had not. Thank you. It works now. My code is slightly different from your suggestion. I will update my question and accept your answer.

Comment: I'd guess for scripts the same is true as for plugins. This means do **not** use `ComponentManager`, but use `ComponentAccessor` like in my anser. ;-)

Comment: @BjörnKautler I replaced `def userSearchService = ComponentManager.getComponentInstanceOfType(UserSearchService.class)` with `def userSearchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(UserSearchService.class)` and that also works. Can you explain *why* your approach is preferred?

Comment: Because the documentation says so. Quote from https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/ComponentManager.html: `Plugins developers should use ComponentAccessor for this, instead.`

Comment: Thank you. That is a very good argument. I will change my code.

Comment: please update your answer @AmedeeVanGasse so that it compiles. You have forgotten about ".class". Thanks for the info i did not know it was preferred the component accesor usage.  Good team work

Comment: I don't understand what I need to update, my code already compiles? Perhaps you don't see the latest version yet because a moderator still needs to approve it?

Comment: Sorry, is not necessary to change this ComponentAccessor.getComponent(UserSearchService)   for this ComponentAccessor.getComponent(UserSearchService.class)?

Comment: But that is what is already there? Are you looking at the part below **EDIT** in bold?

Comment: @Oldskultxo There is no need to write `.class`. In Groovy writing `Foo` is the same as `Foo.class`. You only need the `.class` if use this in Java code. But as the question was about Groovy in ScriptRunner, my answer is perfectly fine. ;-)

Comment: Ok @BjörnKautler. Thanks for the info. Im java developer and starting with groovy... If you take a look, i still write even semicoloms.  ;)  Sorry and thanks.

Comment: Any valid Java code is also valid Groovy code - but not vice versa.