# 404 while trying to use a JIRA Scriptrunner custom REST endpoint

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am trying to add a custom JIRA REST endpoint with Script Runner.

The REST endpoint needs to set user properties: a list of users is provided, and for each user a list of user properties.

This is the script I have cobbled together so far:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.search.UserSearchService
import com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserManager
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

setUserProperties(httpMethod: "POST", groups: ["jira-administrators"])
{ MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body, HttpServletRequest request ->

  def userPropertyManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserPropertyManager()
  def userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager()
  def userSearchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(UserSearchService.class)

  def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body)
  def propertyCount = 0
  def customerList = new ArrayList<>()
  json.each {
    aCustomer ->
      def user = userManager.getUserByName(aCustomer.name.toString())
      aCustomer.properties.each {
        aProperty ->
          userPropertyManager.getPropertySet(user).setString("jira.meta." + aProperty.key.toString(), aProperty.value.toString())
          propertyCount++
      }
      customerList.add(user)
  }

  def response = new ArrayList<>()
  response.add( new JsonSlurper().parseText('{ "properties_changed": ' + propertyCount + ' }') )
  response.add( customerList )

  return Response.ok( new JsonBuilder(response).toPrettyString() ).build();
}
```

<strike>The inline script editor complains about this line: `def user = userManager.getUserByName(aCustomer.name.toString())`, more precisely there is a wavy red line under `aCustomer.name` and the error is</strike>

```
[Static type checking] - No such property: name for class:
java.lang.object
 @ line 28, column 44.
```

***EDIT**: according to @GlennV's answer, this is not really important and can be ignored.*

A previous (working) iteration of this script, running on another server, used email addresses, see [How to get a user by email in JIRA Script Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698657/how-to-get-a-user-by-email-in-jira-script-runner). But, as stated above, now I'm not getting users by email address but by username.

This is the `userprops.json` file I use to test:

```
[
  {
    "name": "felicity.smoak",
    "email": "felicity.smoak@queenconsolidated.com",
    "properties": {
      "Company": "Queen Consolidated",
      "Foo": "bar"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "johnny.cash",
    "email": "johnny.cash@nashville.com",
    "properties": {
      "Company": "Nashville",
      "Nickname": "The Man In Black"
    }
  }
]
```

I test with this `curl` command:

```
curl -X POST \
    -i \
    -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" \
    -H "Content-type: text/json" \
    --data "@userprops.json" \
    -u "$JIRA_USER":"$JIRA_PASSWORD" \
    http://"$JIRA_SERVER"/rest/scriptrunner/latest/custom/setUserProperties
```

`$JIRA_USER`, `$JIRA_PASSWORD` and `$JIRA_SERVER` are just placeholders that I use to anonymize this for Stack Overflow. The actual values are correct.

This is the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 14:55:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-AREQUESTID: 0123456789
X-ASEN: SEN-123456789
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1A2B3C4D5E6F1A2B3C4D5E6F1A2B3C4D5E6F; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP|abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789|lin; Path=/; Secure
X-ASESSIONID: xyz123
X-AUSERNAME: amedee.vangasse
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

So it's not finding the REST endpoint where I should find it according to the [Scriptrunner documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.3/jira/rest-endpoints.html).

If I use any URL that I *know* to be wrong, then I get an expected "Oops, you've found a dead link." error page. Only with the correct URL I get a 404 + no other output.

Also, when I add the `doSomething` sample and try to GET that, I get a 404 and a content length of 0. Doing a GET on any other wrong URL gives me a 404 AND a content length of a few KiB.

The `-Dplugin.script.roots=` parameter is not defined in `setenv.sh`, nor should it be, because the script is inline. Setting script roots is only required for scripts on the filesystem, and only for scripts outside of the default `scripts` directory, as described in the [Scriptrunner documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.6/jira/#_script_roots).

Also asked on [Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/41465294/404-while-trying-to-use-a-jira-scriptrunner-custom-rest-endpoint).

**EDIT**: I moved `customerList.add(user)` one line down as suggested by Glenn, and I got this error in `atlassian-jira.log`:

```
2016-09-09 11:01:43,683 http-nio-8086-exec-23 ERROR amedee.vangasse 661x42160x1 qq01uq 213.224.9.178,127.0.0.1 /rest/scriptrunner/latest/custom/customadmin/com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.common.rest.CustomRestEndpoint [c.a.p.r.c.error.jersey.ThrowableExceptionMapper] Uncaught exception thrown by REST service: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:172)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
        at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.RestEndpointManager$_onFullSystemStart_closure5.doCall(RestEndpointManager.groovy:141)
        ... 3 filtered
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2056)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.RestEndpointManager.onFullSystemStart(RestEndpointManager.groovy:131)
        at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint.refresh(UserCustomScriptEndpoint.groovy:364)
        at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint.saveConfiguredItems(UserCustomScriptEndpoint.groovy:359)
        at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.UserCustomScriptEndpoint.addListener(UserCustomScriptEndpoint.groovy:127)
        ... 3 filtered
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        ... 13 filtered
        at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter$JerseyOsgiServletContainer.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:154)
        ... 1 filtered
        at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:68)
        ... 86 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:70)
        ... 16 filtered
        at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:37)
        ... 73 filtered
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It's not a problem with the nginx proxy either, because when I ssh into the server and `curl` on localhost, I get the same 404.

Answer (score 2):

Script Runner uses Groovy's [CompileStatic](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html) to provide hints about compilation errors. This works fine when sufficient type information is available.

In your code above however, your *json* instance does not contain any type info about the elements it contains, so Groovy (at compilation time) does not know that the *aCustomer* instance has a *name* field, so it warns about it. There is nothing wrong with your code though, so if you send a request to your REST resource, it should work fine.

If your request returns a status code other than 2xx, there is probably something else that goes wrong.

Regarding the 404. This means *Not Found*, so either there's a mistake in the URL that you send the request to, or your REST script is not properly available to Script Runner. I would check the value of $JIRA_SERVER first. If you paste that in a browser, it should properly load JIRA. If that is ok, then I'd check if Script Runner is aware of the path where it needs to look for your scripts. Is the *-Dplugin.script.roots=* parameter defined in your setenv.sh (or setenv.bat) ? More details about this are available [here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.3/jira/DevEnvironment.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Something else must be wrong because if I add `-i` to the `curl` command, then I see that I get a 404. I will modify my question. I'm giving you an upvote because you explained `CompileStatic`.

Comment: `$JIRA_SERVER` is just a placeholder that I used here on Stack Overflow to anonymize. The servername is correct, if it weren't, then I would get other errors. When I paste the servername in a browser, it properly loads JIRA. Script roots is not relevant either because A) While I am debugging, it is an inline script. B) doSomething, the default sample script, also doesn't work.

Comment: That being said, `plugin.script.roots` is not set in `setenv.sh`. Should I set it? Even though I am not using it because the scripts are inline? I also don't use the convoluted dev environment described in your link, I don't use IDEA but vi.

Comment: If your URL is correct then 404 means your REST endpoint is not available to Script Runner. There may be an error related to your script in atlassian-jira.log. Best to check there. I also think that the line "customerList.add(user)" should not be part of the "aCustomer.properties.each" block.

Comment: In `atlassian-jira.log` I only have a `WARN` about `X-Atlassian-Token`, that the `nocheck` value has been deprecated since rest 3.0.0 in favor of `no-check`. I made that change but alas, it made no difference. With regards to `customerList.add(user)`, you are right, I moved that one line down.

Comment: After moving it one line down, I got an error. I added it to my question.

Comment: Something's wrong with how you parse your json input then. But now you're just down to debugging your groovy code. Try out your script in small pieces and fix the errors that pop up one by one. I prefer to do that in an IDE so I can also use unit tests to get things to work.

Comment: There is only one error, and you already said that it doesn't matter because of CompileStatic. And it doesn't explain why `doSomething` doesn't work either?

Comment: I'd need access to your JIRA to figure out what went wrong with doSomething. In any case your REST endpoint is now available to JIRA and Script Runner does execute your script. The error that Script Runner displays on the screen is a hint and in this case can be ignored. You do still get errors at runtime because your scripts takes incorrect actions. These appear in the atlassian-jira.log. You still have to debug those and fix your groovy code (or possibly your json input). I assume you get a 5xx error now instead of a 404.

Comment: I removed my script and kept only `doSomething`. I still get a 404 on https://jira.itextsupport.com/rest/scriptrunner/latest/custom/doSomething. As long as I get a 404 there, it doesn't make sense to try and debug my own custom script.

Comment: In the screen where you configure your endpoints, Script Runner also displays information about how many times a script has run and whether it was succesful. From what you describe, I think for doSomething it will say that that script has not run yet, but for setUserProperties it will say that it has run at least 1 time but encountered an error. I think you're looking at different problems with both scripts.

Comment: I no longer have `setUserProperties`, as mentioned above, I have deleted that. I know what you mean with the information about how many times a script has run, but I don't see it. Not even for `doSomething`. I want to fix the problem with `doSomething` before I continue, and I have a hunch that the other script will also work as soon as `doSomething` works.